# mysql error says unknown column in 'field list', how do i select data in this column?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, create-table

I created two temp tables to join them.

```
create temporary table if not exists dbo.t1 as 
(select * from dbo.cp where id%2=1);

create temporary table if not exists dbo.t2 as 
(select * from dbo.cp where id%2=0);
```

I have two columns in a temporary table: 
When I query

```
select * from dbo.t1;
```

this table comes up.

```
codes  id
123     1
213     2
144     3
423     4
```

My issue: When i say query

```
select codes from dbo.t1;
```

I get the error: `unknown column 'codes' in fieldlist.`

when i query

```
select 'codes` from dbo.t1
```

I get the output

```
codes  id
codes     1
codes     2
codes    3
codes     4
```

when i query

```
select `codes` from dbo.t1
```

I get the output `unknown column in field list`.

This is a huge issue because when I try these different queries to do an inner join I do not get the correct output:

```
Create Table edit AS 
(select 
't1.codes',
t1.id  t1_id, t2.*
from t2
inner join t1 on t1.id = t2.id - 1);

 Create Table edit AS 
    (select 
    t1.codes t1_codes,
    t1.id  t1_id, t2.*
    from t2
    inner join t1 on t1.id = t2.id - 1);



Create Table edit AS 
        (select 
        t1*, t2.*
        from t2
        inner join t1 on t1.id = t2.id - 1);
```

The issue here is I get the error of `"duplicate column name codes"`

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!!  Which one is this????

Comment: This is MySQL..

Comment: Not MySQL with a dbo. construct

Comment: @JessicaWarren If this is MySQL, why do I see SQL Server tag?????

Comment: Because maybe someone who is great at sql server and database theory understands more than me and can explain the theory on these errors... even if they do not know mysql.

Comment: @JessicaWarren People who don't work with MySQL won't know what error 1054 is.

Comment: You should show the code that created this "temporary" table. I feel like you aren't giving the whole story and there is small chance that anyone will be able to help.

Comment: Why would you create table with same name 3 times???  Of course it will error out.

Comment: @UncleCarl You're right I added the code on creating the temp tables.

Comment: How can `select 'codes\` from dbo.t1` produce the output you show? First of all you have unmatched quotes, second you're only selecting one column but the output has two columns. You're not telling us accurately what you did, so it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: `t1` should only contain odd IDs, how can it have `id = 2` and `id = 4`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrapped your code with backtick ( ` ) symbol

```
SELECT `codes` FROM ..
```

Comment: When I use ticks I still get the 1054 error code unknown column

Answer (score 0):

TICKS NOT QUOTES

```
select `codes` from dbo.t1;
```

Comment: When I use ticks I still get the 1054 error code unknown column.

Comment: please explain your answer